# JPA OneToMany relationship maintenance

Tags: hibernate, jpa, one-to-many

I wanted to map a bidirectionnal OneToMany relationship. As the application is responsible of maintaining the sides of relationships, I wrote some code in model objects for that purpose similar to the code proposed in this section : [Wiki Java Persistence page](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/OneToMany#Getters_and_Setters)

When I use my entities, I call the Phone's setOwner method to make the association. Then I persist/merge the Phone entity.

Result is that I see many selection of Phone entities because my relationships are LAZY fetched.

As the above article said, performance can decrease when the collections become large.

So, is there no way to avoid the selections and keep bidirectionnal ?

Answer (score 0):

So, one owner has many phones? In this case, I assume you are saying that when you call `owner.getPhones()` that you are seeing something like:

```
owner ->has phone->has owner ->has phone ->has owner ->has phone ->
```

In large graphs, where phone has (I seek for an example...) multiple sim cards , multiple cases, etc. this can make for large result sets. Remember that these appear to be instantiated objects, but are only proxies.

Yes, if you are into large numbers, it can affect performance. IMO better is to mix JPA with HSQL, or Criteria. I recommend http://uaihebert.com/easycriteria-3-0-new-features/ 
JPA is great in many circumstances, in some cases direct application to the relational is more pertinent.